# 504 bad gateway nginx App engine standard python37 runtime basic_scaling

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using the basic_scaling for a worker service (that needs to run for minutes). And I used to set the basic_scaling in my service configuration in order to have enough execution time.

But, when I did it in a python37 runtime I keep getting `504 Gateway Time-out` error after 60s. Does the python37 support the worker (ex backend) mode ? how should we enable it ?

Comment: have you managed to resolve this? I am hitting the same issue with go1.11 runtime

Comment: it was basically an overload of requests that consumed a lot of memory

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by an overload of requests that consumed a lot of memory.